# Rails4: How to use HTTP instead of HTTPS (SSL) in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, heroku, https

I use a hosting service (not heroku) for Rails4 app.

I can piggyback on the hosting service's SSL certificate for an application running on a hosting service domain like Heroku.

The browser comes to show warning message after using a custom domain, such as www.example.com.

When I type www.example.com, redirect to **https**://www.example.com (SSL).

Please advise me on how to use **http**://www.example.com instead of **https**://www.example.com (SSL).

I don't want to purchase and configure an SSL certificate for my domain so far.

I commented out `config.force_ssl = true` in production.rb.

config\production.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.configure do
  #config.force_ssl = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with 'false' instead of commenting out:

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

Comment: It does not make any difference. The default is `false`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Yasin and @Simone Carletti. It works after saving it in `\config\environments\production.rb` insted of `\config\production.rb`. The file was saved in the wrong path.

Comment: I also needed to set `Rails.application.config.session_store` `cookie_store` option `secure: false` in config/initializers/session_store.rb